# C# VSTO add-in for Excel - Select Chart object by name?

Tags: c#, excel, charts, vsto

I am developing Excel VSTO add-in.
I can programmatically generate several Charts.
Now I want to change type of a series of a certain Chart.
How can I get the Chart object by it's name?

The code below does not work.

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects ChObjs = (ChartObjects)ws.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
 
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject obj = ChObjs.Item("Test Chart");
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? Do you get any exceptions at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the following code snippet below to get Excel sheet Chart object:

```
Excel.Worksheet excSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);//Sheet1
Excel.ChartObjects chartObjects = (Excel.ChartObjects)excSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)chartObjects.Item(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I plan to have multiple chart on 1 sheet, and of course we don't always remember the index of each chart. That is why I need to access chart by it's name. Is there any idea how to do that ?

Comment: You can pass the name instead of its index.

Comment: passing chart name is actually what the thread poster did, but it did not work